# Working out what is a System file in Windows by Java

Tags: java, windows, file

I've noticed that JFileChooser hides Windows System files. Files like hiberfil.sys, pagefile.sys, $Recycle.Bin, a number of shortcut folders that you can't open, etc...

I could hide .sys files in my application but that would only hide a few of them (and not the folders).

I'm guessing it’s a hidden sun only method but I would like to know it, so at least on Oracle Java it will look right.

Note: system files are not hidden files, so hiding hidden files will not work.

Sum up: How to figure out what is a system file/folder using Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't the exact answer but I found out that there is a difference between File.ListFiles and FileSystem.getFiles methods. The getFiles method does not return system files, so you don't need to check if its a system file.

I may also found another way using hidden classes, which I'm researching in.